# Would it be possible to use something like Wikipedia's templates here?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

DISCLAIMER: I've tagged this feature request, but I am aware that such feature will probably difficult to implement. But I'll ask anyway since, I'd like to know the opinion of other users on this.

I was motivated to write this by recent Willie Wong's post about problems with Springer encyclopedia of mathematics: [Link Rot Notice: Springer EOM](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/link-rot-notice-springer-eom).

---

First let me explain what I mean under a *template*. (People active at Wikipedia probably know.) In Wikipedia articles the editors often refer to some sites, like google books, IMDB, PlanetMath,... It makes simpler template to write {{IMDb title|0426883}} instead of writing full url. (I've chosen [this template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:IMDb_title) as an example.) If IMDB would decide to change the structure of their url's but kept the id's, the only change would be needed in one place - in the template. Perhaps you remember that Google books used links like this: http://print.google.com/books?id=CuTpgZaLahk and later they changed to http://books.google.com/books?id=CuTpgZaLahkC - of course this is not an issue, since the older form still redirect to the more recent one. But I wanted just add the example, that things change.

---

Another possible advandatage of such system might be that by typing something like {{Wikipedia|Unimodular group}} you would immediately get e.g [Unimodular group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular%20group) or [Unimodular group at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular%20group), so this could also take care of how your link is named. (Based on the format specified in the template.)

---

In case that the answer would be positive, i.e., that such thing is possible to implement here, I can think of many templates/pages which would be useful specifically for mathematics, first of all MSE, meta.MSE and Mathoverflow, but many more like Wikipedia, ProofWiki, PlanetMath, MathWorld, Springer EOM, Wolfram|Alpha, DOI, JSTOR, MathSciNet...

---

I'm adding links to discussion about similar feature for DOI, since it seems relevant to this question - I learned about them from Asaf's comments.

- [DOI support for hyperlinks at meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104031/doi-support-for-hyperlinks)
- [DOI feature at meta MO](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1147/doi-feature/)

---

Just one last comment - someone might object that by doing this we would be pushing MSE more towards Wikipedia-like design. Let me add here a picture from this [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/adventures-in-delclusionism/) which mentions that *Stack Overflow has elements of wiki in its hybrid design.*

[image: hybrid design of stackoweflow]

Comment: If you think that feature-request tag is really out of place here, please, feel free to retag it with better tags.

Comment: You already mentioned [DOI](http://www.doi.org/), which is one of the solutions that should prevent link-rot. Using the DOI when possible should already eliminate a lot of potential link-rot. For Wikipedia, I think you can safely assume that they won't break links, the links are the titles of the articles already, not some complicated internal system that might change.

Comment: @Fabian: I raised the DOI issue on meta.MO and Willie asked for it on meta.SO as well; from my attempts to figure out the mechanism it is not a trivial matter to resolve DOI automatically, at least it was the case a couple of months ago. Wikipedia may not change the link to the *Set Theory* entry, but it may dissolve some very advanced pages which are short stubs.

Comment: Just a side note: unfortunately this proposal would not have helped the situation with EOM. They changed the IDs, as well as the link structure. Otherwise I'd have just e-mailed the SE team and ask them to run a global search and replace on the database.